# fscanf til EOF to save contents of file word by word

Tags: c, scanf

Hi I'm trying to make a code to read in a file through fscanf to find all the separate words in the file and save it in an array but it's not working. Could you please tell me what's currently wrong in my code?

```
char data[300][45];
char words[100];
char garbage[10];

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int i=0,j;
FILE* file=fopen("week4_data1.in","r");
while((fscanf(file,"%[a-zA-Z]s",data[i++]))!=EOF && (fscanf(file,"%[^a-zA- Z]s",garbage))!=EOF);
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
printf("%s",data[j]);
return 0;
```

}

I'm running it on macs terminal and it compiles well but when I run it I get Bus error: 10.

Oh and this is the contents of the file:

What are algorithms? Why is the study of algorithms worthwhile? What is the role of algorithms relative to other technologies used in computers? In this chapter, we will answer these questions. We can also view an algorithm as a tool for solving a well-specified computational problem. The statement of the problem specifies in general terms the desired input/output relationship. The algorithm describes a specific computational procedure for achieving that input, output relationship. For example, one might need to sort a sequence of numbers into nondecreasing order. This problem arises frequently in practice and provides fertile ground for introducing many standard design techniques and analysis tools. For example, given the input sequence 31, 41, 59, 26, 41, 58, a sorting algorithm returns as output the sequence 26, 31, 41, 41, 58, 59. Such an input sequence is called an instance of the sorting problem. In general, an instance of a problem consists of the input satisfying whatever constraints are imposed in the problem statement needed to compute a solution to the problem. Sorting is a fundamental operation in computer science many programs use it as an intermediate step, and as a result a large number of good sorting algorithms have been developed. Which algorithm is best for a given application depends on-among other factors the number of items to be sorted, the extent to which the items are already somewhat sorted, possible restrictions on the item values, and the kind of storage device to be used: main memory, disks, or tapes. An algorithm is said to be correct if, for every input instance, it halts with the correct output. We say that a correct algorithm solves the given computational problem. An incorrect algorithm might not halt at all on some input instances, or it might halt with an answer other than the desired one. Contrary to what one might expect, incorrect algorithms can sometimes be useful, if their error rate can be controlled. We shall see an example of this in Chapter 31 when we study algorithms for finding large prime numbers. Ordinarily, however, we shall be concerned only with correct algorithms. An algorithm can be specified in English, as a computer program, or even as a hardware design. The only requirement is that the specification must provide a precise description of the computational procedure to be followed.

Comment: Have you heard of paragraphs?

Comment: Please format/indent your question properly.

Comment: this is my first post on stack overflow and the community is a lot more hostile than I thought, yes I understand that it's technically a paragraph but I thought it was enough to get my thought across\

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: See Dilip's answer below.  Break up your actions into steps that can be individually verified/debugged.  That 'while((fscanf' line is a mess that cannot be stepped through.  Think less about 'clever code' and more about 'how can I write my code so that it can be debugged'.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below approach to get things done.

1. Open the file.  *Help : [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)*
2. Check for successful opening. *Hint: Return value.*
3. Read a line from the file. Check for the success. *Help : [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and Return value.*
4. Start tokenizing the read line and store into the array one by one.  *Help : [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)*
5. Continue until token is NULL.
6. Continue until `fgets()` is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The format strings `"%[a-zA-Z]s"` and `"%^[a-zA-Z]s"` are not right. You don't need the `s` in those format strings. Use `"%[a-zA-Z]"` and `"%^[a-zA-Z]"`.

I have a feeling that will fix your problem.

To make your code robust, you should specify the maximum number of characters in the format strings and make sure that `i` does not exceed the valid limit.

```
while( i < 300 &&
       fscanf(file,"%44[a-zA-Z]",data[i++]) != EOF &&
       fscanf(file,"%9[^a-zA-Z]",garbage) != EOF );
```